# Switching of summation indices in Analytic Number Theory

Tags: summation, analytic-number-theory

I was reading a proof of “Generalised Convolution” in Tom Apostol’s Analytical Number Theory. I seem to have lost my mind in trying to figure out how the switch in the summation indices is performed (page 39 of the book)

The equation goes like this:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\alpha(n) \sum_{m\leq \frac{x}{n}}\beta(m)F( \frac{x}{mn}) $$
And switching it to this is (confusing me part 1):
$$\sum_{mn\leq x}\alpha(n)\beta(m)F(\frac{x}{mn}) $$
The above equation is again switched to (confusing me part 2):
$$\sum_{k\leq x}\left(\sum_{n|k} \alpha(n) \beta(k/n)\right)F(\frac{x}{k}) $$
Please help.

Comment: $\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{m\le x/n}$ is the same as $\sum_{mn\le x}$. For the part 2 you meant $\sum_{k\leq x} \sum_{n|k}\alpha(n)\beta(k/n)F(\frac{x}{mn})$. Simply set $k=mn$ to get that $\sum_{mn\le x}$ is the same as $\sum_{k\le x}\sum_{n|k, m=k/n}$

Comment: How can I prove that it is the same? That’s what screwing my mind. The first part, could you please expand on that?

Comment: @JyotishrajThoudam Sketch a hyperbola and you will see

Comment: I think I understand. As n goes from $1$ to $x$. The terms are constrained via the multiplication $mn \leq x$, therefore, the constraint is the only necessary condition, in order to open the sum and gather the $\alpha(n)$ term to the right. Again, playing with it, if we again want to put a free sum, we apply another constraint hence sum condition $n|k$ is inserted.

Comment: @TravorLZH Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to write the index region with some additional information. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}}&\color{blue}{\alpha(n)\sum_{1\leq m\leq \frac{x}{n}}\beta(m)F\left(\frac{x}{mn}\right)}\\
&=\sum_{{1\leq n\leq nm\leq x}\atop{1\leq m}}\alpha(n)\beta(m)F\left(\frac{x}{mn}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{{1\leq n\leq k\leq x}\atop{n\mid k}}\alpha(n)\beta(k/n)F\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{1\leq k\leq x}\left(\sum_{{n\mid k}\atop{1\leq n}}\alpha(n)\beta(k/n)\right)F\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}
\end{align*}
according to the claim. We observe in the last line we have just exchanged inner and outer sum of the first line.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the index region as inequality chain, multiplying the index region of the inner sum with $n$.
- In (2) we substitute $k=m n$.